# Does a PoA based permissioned blockchain relies on cryptocurrency as tokens?

Tags: blockchain

I am studying different categories of blockchain.

Since the validator nodes are pre defined in the PoA based blockchain, and also mining is not required to determine the next valid block.

Is it required to have a cryptocurrency as tokens in the PoA based blockchain? If yes, what is it's role?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary, no, but it's often included anyway depending on the use case. Public PoA blockchains, like xDai and Kovan, still have transaction fees to make it so spamming has a cost.